# Display a rails partial site wide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app with several views and layouts. One of my layouts is called `user_admin`. In here I have a sidebar where I'd like like to display all registered "Tenants".

I have a properties dashboard which contains a tenant partial and work fine. To get the above idea working in the side bar I created a shared partial and then link to it with

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/sidebar_tenant_list", :locals=>{ :tenants => @property.tenants} %>
```

This works fine in my properties dashboard with my tenant partial but when I move to a different page of my site I get

```
undefined method `tenants' for nil:NilClass
```

Extracted source (around line #133):

```
131:  <!-- Sidebar List -->
132:                
133:  <%= render :partial => "shared/sidebar_tenant_list", :locals=>{ :tenants => @property.tenants} %>
134:                
135:  <!-- /Sidebar List -->
```

Is there a way that I can make this available to all views throughout the site?

Thanks for the help...T

Comment: It sounds like @property is null on the other pages. Are you setting that variable everywhere you want to use it?

Comment: What's in `@property` object? If it's kind of static you could use a helper instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/sidebar_tenant_list", :locals=>{ :tenants => @property.tenants} %>
```

You can write

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/sidebar_tenant_list", :locals=>{ :tenants => Tenant.all } %>
```

So all Tentants will be displayed in your partial. And not bound to a environment variable.

Comment: not a good solution - @property may have only certain tenants and not all of them.

Comment: Thread opener wrote explicit `I'd like like to display all registered "Tenants".` and that he already has a partial which could do this but only works in the specific action.

Comment: Simple and it works! Thanks for that works like a charm. I should have picked up on it.

Comment: sorry @davidb, didn't see that +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a :before_filter to the ApplicationController, which would be executed before each action in every controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :load_property

  def load_property
    @property = ...Whatever...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be that `@property` is nil, the @property must be available wherever you use this partial sidebar snippet which calls `@property.tenants`

A possible solution might be a before_filter in your controller that looks up @property like:

```
class SidebarController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :lookup_property

   def lookup_property
     @property = YourProperyModel.find(...)
   end
end


# any controller that needs a sidebar
class SomeControllerWithSidebar < SidebarController
  # some sugar if it's not possible to lookup @property for a certain action
  skip_before_filter :lookup_property, :only => [:new]

  # any action 
  def someaction
 end
```

end